# Отладка decompiled sources - `The breakpoint failed to bind`

Tags: отладка, visual-studio-2017, breakpoint

Дебажу падающий тест (*падает по причине эксепшена в сторонней библиотеке*), используя декомпилированные ресурсы. Текста ошибки нет, есть только стек-трейс. Само исключение кастомное, библиотечное, так что о его природе тоже особо ничего не известно. Пробую прогнать через дебаг следующий метод из сторонней библиотеки, который и провоцирует исключение, чтобы понять что там происходит:

```
public Engine Execute(Program program)
    {
      this.ResetStatementsCount();
      this.ResetTimeoutTicks();
      this.ResetLastStatement();
      this.ResetCallStack();
      using (new StrictModeScope(this.Options._IsStrict || program.Strict, false))
      {
        this.DeclarationBindingInstantiation(DeclarationBindingType.GlobalCode, program.FunctionDeclarations, program.VariableDeclarations, (FunctionInstance) null, (JsValue[]) null);
        Completion completion = this._statements.ExecuteProgram(program);
        if (completion.Type == Completion.Throw)
          throw new JavaScriptException(completion.GetValueOrDefault()) { Location = completion.Location };
        this._completionValue = completion.GetValueOrDefault();
      }
      return this;
    }
```

Брекпоинты ставятся и срабатывают только на строках не входящих в блок `using` При попытке установить брекпоинт в режиме рантайма внутри `using` появляется хинт, что брекпоинт не может быть установлен в этом месте. Если брекпоинт установить до запуска, то он просто не срабатывает.

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогичный вопрос но для другой версии Visual Studio задавали на английском SO: [Breakpoint Failed to Bind - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732944). Вопрос получил множество ответов. Я поддерживаю [вот этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32213614/1101913) ответ, потому что аналогичное решение помогло мне в прошлом.

При компилировании байт кода в машинный код JIT компилятор может выполнять некоторые преобразования в целях оптимизации производительности. Эти преобразования зачастую мешают отлаживать код, и они отключаются при сборке проекта в Debug режими.

Visual Studio 2017 предоставляет возможность отключить оптимизацию даже при отладке кода, который собран в режиме Release. Для этого, достаточно включить опцию [Suppress JIT optimization on module load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/jit-optimization-and-debugging?view=vs-2017) в настройках.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо этого, можно попробовать такой трюк. Поставить точку останова в ближайшем месте, переключиться в режим Disassembly, и пошагово выполнять код клавишей F11 (с заходом в функцию), чтобы не перепрыгиывать через нужный код. Этот прием описан здесь: [Debugging Optimized Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/08/14/debugging-optimized-code/).

Comment: Да, логично, using ведь просто сахар. Спасибо за наводку, попробую варианты.